# union of two mongoDB documents

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I have many documents in which `"name"` is there, now I have to find the union of documents having same name value, like eg:

```
{"name":"apple iphone 6","memory":"32GB"},
{"name":"apple iphone 6","memory":"16GB"}
```

required result is

```
{"name":"apple iphone 6","memory":"16GB/32GB"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get result by aggregation

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    { "$group" : { 
           "_id" : "$name", 
           "memory": { "$addToSet": "$memory" }  
    }}
]);
```

Output will be

```
{ "_id": "apple iphone 6", "memory": ["16GB", "32GB"]}
```

Then use array join method on result.memory

Comment: is it possible to do nested query in this like " Memory.Internal" instead of memory

Comment: yes you can do so using  $memory.Internal  check mongo aggregation before proceeding